# Passing templated constexpr to function inferring type of auto object

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I'm making an entity-component system library utilizing template metaprogramming to evaluate signature bitset data at compile-time and allow for precise bitset size without using `#define MAX_COMPONENTS some-number`.
I'm using Boost Hana and have a function which should look like this:

```cpp
template <auto T>
  static constexpr Bitset signatureBitset = Bitset(
    hana::fold(SignatureList[hana::integral_c<std::size_t, signatureID<T>>], 0,
    [](auto l, auto r) {
      return l | 1 << inferProperty<primitiveBit>(r);
    }));
```

What it does is calculate constexpr Bitset for given signature. Signature is a *hana::tuple_t* of ECS component and tag types. 
`primitiveBit` returns bit offset of template argument type component/tag. As *hana::fold* lambda doesn't provide type of current `r`, I can't simply call `primitiveBit<RType>` (RType is not defined).

Simplest possible solution would be to write a duplicate of every template "function" but as an actual constexpr function instead of static constexpr object but I'm trying to avoid that as writing 30+ duplicate function which all do

```cpp
template <typename T>
static constexpr auto inferFunctionName(hana::basic_type<T> t) {
    return functionName<T>;
}
```

seems dumb and will make everything harder to maintain. The above code also looks very simple and like it can be abstracted away using template function taking template constexpr object as a template parameter.

This is what I currently have:

```cpp
template <template<typename> typename TReturn, typename T>
constexpr auto inferProperty(hana::basic_type<T> t) {
    return TReturn<T>();
}
```

`inferProperty<primitiveBit>(r)` throws a compile error saying it doesn't match defined template signature.

Using `template <template<typename T> typename TReturn, typename T>` isn't an option due to `T` not being defined within lambdas.

Comment: Is there some reason `decltype(r)` doesn't work inside the lambda?

Comment: @JackC. Type is wrapped within hana::basic_type<T>, so decltype(r) is hana::basic_type<actual-type>.
After derping around with it a bit, `typename decltype(r)::type` is the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, as said by Jack C. in the comments, is to use `decltype(r)` inside lambda to get type from object instead of inferring type through template functions.

Which means `propertyCheck<typename decltype(r)::type>` works.